How often does a user need to re-login to the Autodesk APS platform?
I'm writing a web application that performs the Autodesk APS design automation, and it requires a user to login so I can retrieve a 3-legged OAuth token. I know that I can use the refresh token once within a 15-day period, but how long can I keep getting refresh tokens for a user before the user will need to re-login to my application? Is it indefinitely, or is there a time limit if I'm refreshing the token once per hour, for example?

After the refresh token expires (14 days), the user will need to re-login to your application to obtain a new set of access and refresh tokens.
